# Unnest MariaDB, other method?

Tags: sql, json, nested, mariadb, unnest

as far as I know mariadb does not support the unnest function bigquery is using. Is there a method i don´t know about in mariadb to unnest data?

[image: Properties is nested]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid inserting images showing code and data. Instead paste it into your question indented four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that `properties` column contains JSON.  Try using [JSON_DETAILED()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_detailed/).

```
SELECT JSON_DETAILED(properties) ...
```